# How setup Thrift on windows using Intellij

Tags: java, thrift

I'm trying to create Thrift client project in Intellij on windows. I found many references how to create Thrift client using java in Intellij. But the problem is cannot add following references to the project. I am new to Thrif and Java.

```
import org.apache.thrift.TException;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.TSSLTransportParameters;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol;
```

what is the technique or method to setup on windows and import above libraries?

Answer (score 1):

These instructions are not specific to your IDE, but neither is your problem.  The library classes for Thrift are in libthrift-*.jar, and you'll need to add that to your project just as you would any other JAR.

If you are using maven, you can add the maven coordinates to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
    <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Alternatively you can just download the JAR and add it your project:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/thrift/libthrift/0.9.1/libthrift-0.9.1.jar

If you are using a version that has not been published to the central maven repositories, you can download the source tarball and navigate to the `lib/java` directory and build it with Apache Ant by typing:

```
ant
```

The library JAR will be in the `lib/java/build` directory.  Optionally you can add the freshly built JAR to your local Maven repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -DartifactId=libthrift -DgroupId=org.apache.thrift -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DpomFile=build/libthrift-1.0.0.pom -Dfile=build/libthrift-1.0.0.jar
```